# create language error in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I tried to create a language `pltcl` in postgresql. But, I got this error.

```
postgres=# CREATE LANGUAGE 'pltcl';
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/pltcl": No such file or directory


postgres=# select * from pg_pltemplate;
 tmplname  | tmpltrusted | tmpldbacreate |      tmplhandler      |   tmplvalidator   |   tmpllibrary    | tmplacl 
-----------+-------------+---------------+-----------------------+-------------------+------------------+---------
 plpgsql   | t           | t             | plpgsql_call_handler  | plpgsql_validator | $libdir/plpgsql  | 
 pltcl     | t           | t             | pltcl_call_handler    |                   | $libdir/pltcl    | 
 pltclu    | f           | f             | pltclu_call_handler   |                   | $libdir/pltcl    | 
 plperl    | t           | t             | plperl_call_handler   | plperl_validator  | $libdir/plperl   | 
 plperlu   | f           | f             | plperl_call_handler   | plperl_validator  | $libdir/plperl   | 
 plpythonu | f           | f             | plpython_call_handler |                   | $libdir/plpython |
```

After referred the internet, I got the answer. That is,

`In order to get pltcl.so you will need to compile the postgres code using --with-tcl configure switch. pltcl does not compile by default with postgres.`

How to fix this problem?

Comment: How did you install postgresql? From source?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the `postgresql-pltcl-9.1` package, replacing the 9.1 with the postgres version you're using if it's different.

Comment: [Here](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=postgresql) you can find all PostgreSQL packages provided by Debian.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-pltcl-9.6 postgresql-plperl-9.6
```